# Validate URL in android over network call

Tags: android

I am making an app where i have a url with date.I need to check if the url has data and if it had data then add date to list.I have made a method which i have posted below and it is being call on main thread.But the problem is it takes few seconds to start the app.I need to optimise the app.Is there any other way to "REDUCE THE LOADING TIME".

> Code

```
   private List<String> getDateList(int counter, String date) { 
 String urlth = "https://www.example.com/json/" + date.trim().replaceAll("/", "") + "-12.json";
    if (validateUrl.exists(urlth)) {
        dateList.add(date);
    } else {
        date = givePreviousDate(date);
        return getDateList(counter, date);
    }
    if (dateList.size() == 7) {
        return dateList;
    } else {
        date = givePreviousDate(date);  //gives previous date
        return getDateList(++counter, (date));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `handler` to call your method in background, something like this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
ListView<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //call your method here
        myList = getDateList(2, "date"); //with int and date data
    }
});
```

Hope this will help!